# Where does Firefox (Quantum) download updates prior to restart, and what should I delete to prevent a current update to occur after a restart?

Tags: firefox, auto-update

Where does Firefox Quantum download updates prior to restart, and what should I delete to prevent a current update to occur after a restart? I want to manually update Firefox every time, but this time it I downloaded the update file by accident, and it's waiting for me to restart. I wish to locate it and delete it, so where is it storing it?  I found the following

```
/Users/[user]/Library/Caches/Mozilla/updates/Applications/Firefox/updates/0
```

but I don't recognize nor understand the files within it as:

```
update.mar
update.status
update.version
```

So I'm leery to delete these.

Comment: `update.mar` is a binary file that for v64.0 is 31648712 bytes
`update.status` is a text file that for v64.0 contains "pending"
`update.version` is a text file that for v64.0 contains "64.0"
I've made a TM backup for the moment. Given the above information, I'm going to delete these three files, and if there's a failure, I'll post back.